# Can Newton's law of cooling explain Mpemba effect?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

Newton's Law of cooling states that the rate of loss of heat in proportional to the temperature difference. or
$-dQ/dt = k(T' - T)$

Q → heat transferred,
t → time,
k → constant,
T' - T → temperature difference.

Anyone not knowing about Mpemba effect here's [a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect)

Comment: your question is very vague. Please improve it by explaining what is Mpemba effect and how do you want the two things to be connected.

Comment: Newton's Law of cooling doesn't "explain" anything. It's just a mathematical equation. For the Mpemba effect, it completely ignores phase changes (i.e. evaporation) and radiative heat loss. Even in situation where it is relevant, the *physics* is what determines the value of the "constant" $k$ - and in most real world situations $k$ is *not* constant!

Answer (score 2):

This seems more of p-chem problem than physics.

The Mpemba effect is that hot water will freeze faster than cold water which is counter intuitive.

Actually Newton's Law of cooling would predict that cold water would freeze faster than hot. If the hot water is a temperature $\text{T}_\text{H}$ and the cold water is at $\text{T}_\text{C}$ then the hot water would have to cool through temperature $\text{T}_\text{C}$ to reach the freezing point. So hot water should take longer.